# SQL Server XQuery.modify "Syntax error near ':', expected '}'"

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Table Test.User contains one field "Details" which is in XML type.
The Details value of user which Id is 1024 is in the following format:

```
<Details>
  <Name>Kevin</Name>
  <Age>23</Age>
</>Details>
```

I try to insert a new node "Address" into this xml value likes this:

```
UPDATE Test.User
SET Details.modify('insert <Address>{0:c0}</Address> into (/Details)[1]')
WHERE Id = 1024
```

But error occurs, please help advise on it.

> "Syntax error near ':', expected '}'"

Comment: u want to update Details column

Comment: Yes, it seems that need to make a conversion for symbol ":"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape these types of `{0:c0}` markup characters  with [CDATA section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA)

```
DECLARE @DETAILS XML ='<Details>
  <Name>Kevin</Name>
  <Age>23</Age>
</Details>'

SELECT @DETAILS


SET @DETAILS.modify('insert <Address><![CDATA[{0:c0}]]></Address>   into (/Details)[1]')

SELECT @DETAILS
```

Then the result will be like

```
<Details>
  <Name>Kevin</Name>
  <Age>23</Age>
  <Address>{0:c0}</Address>
</Details>
```

Comment: It works for me, and the reference is really useful, thanks a lot.