# SQL Exception calling ExecuteScalar: "XQuery [query()]: Syntax error near 'in', expected '}'."

Tags: sql-server, xquery, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to show how Microsoft software (i.e. SQL Server) could run an XQuery, similar to what I have done using SAXON.

From SSMS, I can run this query with success.  I stuffed the entire OpenRowSet in the Select so I could run use the .ExecuteScalar method from PowerShell or C#.

```
SELECT Cast((SELECT BulkColumn FROM   OPENROWSET(BULK'c:\XMLClass\Shakespeare\Hamlet\hamlet.xml',SINGLE_CLOB) as myalias) as XML).query(
'
 <html><body>
 {
   for $act in //ACT
   return $act 
 }
 </body></html>
 ')
```

Next, I want to run the same exact command in PowerShell, capture the results, and write it to a file:

```
$datasource = "server=(local);database=master;trusted_connection=true"

$connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection($connectionString)
$connection.open()
Write-Host "SQL Connection Opened" 

$SQLScalarCommand = @"

SELECT Cast((SELECT BulkColumn FROM   OPENROWSET(BULK'c:\XMLClass\Shakespeare\Hamlet\hamlet.xml',SINGLE_CLOB) as myalias) as XML).query(
'
 <html><body>
 {
   for $act in //ACT
   return $act 
 }
 </body></html>
 ') 

"@

#Write-Host $SQLScalarCommand 

$Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand 
$Command.Connection = $connection 
$Command.CommandText = $SQLScalarCommand 

$SQLResult = $Command.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
Write-Host ("Result=$SQLResult") 

$connection.close()
```

Getting SQL command reported from PowerShell:

> Exception calling "ExecuteScalar" with "0" argument(s): "XQuery
>   [query()]: Syntax error near 'in', expected '}'." At
>   C:\XMLClass\XQuery\Shakespeare_Powershell_SQL_Simpler.ps1:43 char:1

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42108713/sql-server-xquery-modify-syntax-error-near-expected), but didn't seem to apply in my case. 
My Xquery did more, but I tried to simplify it down to one "for/in" statement for purposes of illustration.

Select @@Version shows this:

Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: )

PowerShell Version: 5.1.17763.316

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell string interpolation is replacing `$act` with powershell variables.
In Powershell double-quoted strings and here-strings perform variable string interpolation, and single-quoted strings and here-strings do not.  See [about_Quoting_Rules: HERE-STRINGS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7#here-strings).

See:

```
$SQLScalarCommand = @"

SELECT Cast((SELECT BulkColumn FROM   OPENROWSET(BULK'c:\temp\hamlet.xml',SINGLE_CLOB) as myalias) as XML).query(
'
 <html><body>
 {
   for $act in //ACT
   return $act 
 }
 </body></html>
 ') 

"@

Write-Host $SQLScalarCommand
```

outputs

```
SELECT Cast((SELECT BulkColumn FROM   OPENROWSET(BULK'c:\temp\hamlet.xml',SINGLE_CLOB) as myalias) as XML).query(
'
 <html><body>
 {
   for  in //ACT
   return  
 }
 </body></html>
 ')
```

Should be something like

```
$SQLScalarCommand = @'

SELECT Cast((SELECT BulkColumn FROM   OPENROWSET(BULK'c:\temp\hamlet.xml',SINGLE_CLOB) as myalias) as XML).query(
'
 <html><body>
 {
   for $act in //ACT
   return $act 
 }
 </body></html>
 ') 

'@

Write-Host $SQLScalarCommand
```

Comment: Thanks, I was focusing on SQL instead of PowerShell! 
I just put a grave-accent in front the $ signs.  I don't see that in your suggestion above.  Are they not showing up, or did you have another approach?

Comment: Ah, nevermind - I see you changed double quote to single quote on the here-string.  Thanks!

Comment: That's fine.  You can also use single-quoted string literals to prevent the variable replacement.

Comment: Hmmm,.. I get a response and store to file now, but it seems to be the entire XML. Am I doing something wrong cramming the Cast, and the OpenRowset all onto that one line?

Comment: No, It has the <html><body> at top, and it's different. 
But it's definitely different from what SAXON.exe gave me, and what I get when I run in SSMS.

Comment: Trying to increase SQL timeout - maybe that's the issue.

Comment: Should be the same as SSMS if the query is the same.  The query you posted will output the child nodes of ACT.  Perhaps something like `return $act/text()`

Comment: Yes, the timeout was causing the odd results.  Increased to 180 seconds.